# AS3 Error 1010, variables declared and properties universal?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

These two for loops that I'm going to use 1 to score points and 1 to remove lives, are causing an AS3 error #1010, "A term is undefined and has no properties" however I define both arrays in my constructor code and define the for loop variable in the for loop.
It also doesn't make it into the second for loop despite doing things that come after it in the main function. Any help?

```
                    for (var iPlus = 0; iPlus <= objectArrayPlus.length; iPlus++)
                {
                    if (objectArrayPlus[iPlus].y >= 400)
                    {
                        removeChild(objectArrayPlus[iPlus]);
                        objectArrayPlus.splice(iPlus, 1);
                    }
                    else if (gameBoat.hitTestObject(objectArrayPlus[iPlus]))
                    {
                        trace("this will score");
                    }
                }
                for (var iMinus:int = 0; iMinus <= objectArrayMinus.length; iMinus++)
                {
                    trace ("for loop entered");
                    if (objectArrayMinus[iMinus].y >= 150)
                    {
                        removeChild(objectArrayMinus[iMinus]);
                        objectArrayMinus.splice(iMinus, 1);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `<` instead of `<=` in your `for` loops :

```
for (var iPlus:int = 0; iPlus < objectArrayPlus.length; iPlus++) {

    ...

}

for (var iMinus:int = 0; iMinus < objectArrayMinus.length; iMinus++) {

     ...

}
```

Comment: this was it, seems obvious now but for anyone who had the same problem as me - the array length will be the full number of elements in the array, but since the array indexes from 0 it gets to an iteration where there is no array element and stops. Thanks akmozo

Answer (score 0):

A likely cause for at least the reason why the second loop is skipped is that one or both of your arrays are empty. I can't tell as I don't know what goes on with those arrays earlier, but if their are no terms in those arrays then that might be part of the problem. Again, it would be useful to have some more detail, if you could show where those variables/lists are defined and added to, might be able to help more.

Comment: i trace the array lengths in the function to check that and they do both contain elements, the push and splice removal seem to be working correctly in the first, and i know the push is working correctly in the second, it isn't actually entering the second loop

Comment: Can you add some more of the code so we can see the loops in context?